# Is "Luisa" in this sentence the indirect object or direct object?

Tags: objetos-indirectos, objetos-directos

> Estaba allí Luisa y la observé sin que mi viera.

I think Luisa is the indirect object. Why is she actually the direct object? I'm asking why she's the direct object because "la" signifies direct object, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luisa is both subject (of your first clause) and, as you deduce, direct object (in the second clause).  To roughly gauge what the direct and indirect objects are, you can formulate a question with the subject and the verb:

. ¿Qué observé yo? <sub>*direct object*</sub>
 . *o bien* ¿Quién observé yo? <sub>*direct object*</sub>
 . ¿Para quién observé yo? <sub>*indirect object*</sub>
 . *o bien* ¿Para qué (cosa) observé yo? <sub>*indirect object*</sub>

In this case, you can ask "What or whom did I observe?" or "For what (thing) or for whom did I observe?" (in other words, who benefited from my observations?).  "she" (or "her) is the answer to the first question, so it's a direct object that we're dealing with, rather than an indirect object.

Comment: In this case I think "la" (Luisa) can be seen as either direct or indirect object: _¿A quién observé yo?_, were she is "el beneficiario o destinatario de la acción" (http://lema.rae.es/drae/srv/search?id=AWr5ed9dGDXX2lNuZY1h#complemento_indirecto.). It is an ambiguous case where both interpretations are valid. Nevertheless, in "_a_ quién observé" it is mandatory the "_a_" when observing people or a person.

Comment: @Lucas for her to be the indirect object, it'd need to be "le observé". It's true that "a Luisa" is ambiguous (hence I used para in the example) but speaking as a laísta, for me to interpret the *la* in "la observé", I'd need a direct object elsewhere in the clause: "La observé el experimento" or something. Historically though, some of the perceptive verbs did alternate some in transitiveness.